# missing utility.hpp in opencv 2.4.6

Tags: c++, opencv

I am using opencv 2.4.6 which I believe is the latest version.

I am trying to test with ocl module and developing an application like this:

https://github.com/nzjrs/opencv/blob/master/samples/ocl/surf_matcher.cpp

But I am getting error that

opencv2/core/utility.hpp

is not available. Looking at opencv directory, I can see that it is not in opencv include directory.

Where can I download it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you're on the  2.4 branch, you probably should use the respective 2.4 sample code instead

https://github.com/itseez/opencv/blob/2.4/samples/ocl/surf_matcher.cpp

(also, better off getting stuff from github/itseez.org, instead  from a fork)